# Listener not found in SharpSnmpLib v11.2

Tags: c#, .net, snmp, sharp-snmp

I had a Listener setup for SNMP Traps using SharpSnmpLib v11.1 that I grabbed from Nuget.org.  I noticed there was an update to this package to v11.2.  When I updated, there was no longer a reference to the Listener.

I cannot find where this function has moved to in the [documentation](https://docs.sharpsnmp.com/).  Where has this functionality moved to?

As per the instructions [here](https://github.com/lextudio/sharpsnmplib) I am posting my question here with the appropriate tag.

**UPDATE**

I know the listener has been removed, I am looking for the function that listens for the Trap message coming in.

**UPDATE 2**

Here is what I am seeing after performing the update with the Nuget Package Manager
[image: Code Screenshot]

Comment: https://github.com/lextudio/sharpsnmplib-samples/tree/master/Samples/CSharpCore/snmptrapd

Comment: So I added 'using Listener = Lextm.SharpSnmpLib.Pipeline.Listener;' to my code and I get an error under 'Pipeline' stating: The type or namespace name 'Pipeline' does not exist in the Namespace. I updated to v11.2.0 via Nuget Manager in VS.

Comment: Clone the samples from GitHub and study the code. Then you need no one to answer for you.

Comment: I did that.  What I am seeing is that after updating the library from the Nuget manager to v11.2, it says pipeline does not exist in the using statement.  Is it possible that the build in the Nuget library does not have the references?

Comment: No, you didn't. Do open the sample project (snmptrapd) in Visual Studio and check from where the classes come from. Don't make a rather simple thing that complex.

Comment: @LexLi I see the Listener in (solution)SharpSnmpLib.Samples : (project) SharpSnmpLib.Engine/Pipeline/Listener.  But if you look at my attached photo, it is not referencing in the update package I got from the VS Nuget package Manager.  Please forgive my ignorance.  I have only delved into the SNMP world 6 months ago.

Comment: In short, you no longer should expect everything from the NuGet package, and have to add certain classes from the sample repo. That's just what I said above and I won't comment more.

Comment: @LexLi That was what I was missing.  I was under the assumption that Nuget would always have what I need.  I appreciate your time on this.

Comment: It's not very strange that OP wonders about this, I was also looking for it, because it was in the API docs.

Answer (score 2):

If someones still looking for the Listener. It was moved into the "Engine" Namespace.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/SharpSnmpLib.Engine/

Answer (score 1):

The Listener was removed in this commit:

https://github.com/lextudio/sharpsnmplib/commit/3256c88d63bcb812f7f9ca470cbcd5f0d21210a4

---

The autor moved the Listener to the samples repository:

https://github.com/lextudio/sharpsnmplib-samples/commit/e729b167ba69e5e4dd386d42ad7d519927a16ae8#diff-39dd1695679daed1c64bc2f1cdf1df2d

---

You can clearly read it on the release info:

https://github.com/lextudio/sharpsnmplib/releases/tag/11.2.0

Comment: I know. I asked where the functionality went, not the class so much. How does one listen for a trap message?